# WCF Data services conditional query interceptor

Tags: c#, c#-4.0, wcf-data-services

I have a wcf data service that is being consumed by my applications within my organization. It contains the following entities:

```
Client
User
Membership
```

The data is set-up in as multi-tenant and currently requires what we call a client string, or the string representation of the clients unique id, to be passed-in as part of the path and I extract that and add that in a query interceptor as a filter. This has worked beautifully up until recently when we had a new client come on-board that has a parent clientstring with many children. So the result is a query that includes a list of clientids passed-in for all queries as an "in (.....)". Not too bad but when this client now attempts to query memberships they have 9k+ clientids passed-in. The resultant query seems to run fairly quickly when executed alone but the entire db transaction is taking >30 seconds consistently.

I would ultimately like to find a way to bypass this filter for such queries if a specific userid is provided. The URL looks like this:

http://service.com/clienta/Users(1234)/memberships

If a specific id is given for users or memberships I can avoid the filter as the effectively achieves the same end-result. What we can't have is someone doing something like this:

http://service.com/clienta/memberships

Without any filter.

I realize this may be scattered and require much more detail as this was a bit rushed. Please ask any questions. Any help or guidance is much appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

Can you use a query interceptor to intercept the request then if your condition is met to avoid the filtering, simply ignore it?

You could also move to a Service Method and pass in your arguments and do just about anything you want to do.

Comment: That was pretty-much my fallback plan if I could not create a more blanket appoach like a conditional interceptor. I'm guessing I will have to go that route. Do you happen to know if there is an easy way to determine if an id has been provided? I can use a regex but would prefer to avoid that if there is a mechanism within the framework to specify this. Thank you for the response!

Comment: With a Service Method, you can pass in anything you want from the client. It could be your main parameter you'd like. Then you can just check to see if the parameter is null and go from there.

Comment: For a query intecepter route, you don't have access to the query string.For the query interceptor, now that I think about it, i don't know that i've been able to grab the request url so that I can see the params, I believe the interceptor purely adds additional url params. However, if you know what users are having that issue, you could check the active user with the query interceptor, then add further filters to the url to limit their records and let the users without problems continue normally. Similar to this: bondigeek.com/blog/2010/09/06/…